I would like to ask why , when I do php bin/magento s:upgrade or s:s:d -f it load time take like hour?
Sometimes it Load almost 5-6 hour, one module it take 43 min


Login to your database and run the follow command
show processlist;

this command will show which database query Is running at that time and you can start your debugging from there.


Generally this commands do not take this much of time.
In your case, if that take this time then you can verify following things.
A. Check your server configuration are proper according to magento version requirements.
B. Check your Magento Installation do not have any issues.
C. Check theme, if it has any issues like this.
D. Check All Third Party Extensions one by one, if any of those have this issue.
